# Jhipster does not run in eclipse using run as spring boot application

Tags: jhipster

When I am using runAs inside eclipse I am always getting this error.

`Error: Could not find or load main class com.xx.api.Application`

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your version of Eclipse, on what you have installed, on how you configured everything...
What you can do:

- Install Spring Tool Suite : it's an Eclipse version with everything already set up, so you can get started quickly
- Use JHipster's new [Vagrant devbox](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-devbox) which will give you a virtualized environment with everything pre-configured for you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for looking into this. I am using Spring Tool Suite. I am trying to use gradle eclipse plugin. This is where i was getting errors.

When i switched to import project as gradle project It started working. However I have generated DTO using the jhipster-uml.

This generate the mapper classes in build folder by default. Now when i run the application, It fails to find mapper classes.

I am able to make is work by generating the mapper classes into my source folder for now.

Thanks for help.